# Vue: Passing multiple @click into components

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a blade view template that I pass in a parent function like so:

```
<Flash 
    :flash-status="flashStatus" 
    :flash-content="flashContent"
    v-if="flashStatus === true"
    @click="hideFlashMsg">

</Flash>
```

but now I need to pass another function in and tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<Flash 
    :flash-status="flashStatus" 
    :flash-content="flashContent"
    v-if="flashStatus === true"
    @click="hideFlashMsg"
    @click="addNums">

</Flash>
```

How do I setup two event listeners for the same event?

Answer (score 2):

You can call multiple click functions like so:

```
@click="hideFlashMsg(); addNums();"
```

Or, have one function handle multiple other functions.

```
clickhandler(){
    this.function1();
    this.function2();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`v-on`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) directive can take an object that sets up multiple listeners for the same event:

```
{
  EVENTNAME: [HANDLER_1, HANDLER_2, ... HANDLER_N]
}
```

So you could do:

```
<Flash v=on"{ click: [hideFlashMsg, addNums] }" />
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    hideFlashMsg() {
      console.log('hideFlashMsg')
    },
    addNums() {
      console.log('addNums')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.9"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-on="{click: [hideFlashMsg, addNums]}">Click</button>
</div>
```